# Не работает редирект статических страниц nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

Вот мой конфиг:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name dev2.site.com www.dev2.site.com;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;    

    server_tokens off;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name dev2.site.com www.dev2.site.com;

    ########################
    # ssl config
    ########################

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev2.site.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev2.site.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000";

    ssl_stapling on;

    ssl_stapling_verify on;



    #######################

    server_tokens off;


    location ~* ^.+\.(rss|woff2|svg|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|rtf|js|css)$ {
        expires 2592000;
        etag off;
    }

    #error_log /var/www/error.log;

    root /var/www/dev2.site.com;

    index index.php  index.html;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types image/svg+xml text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?query_string;
    }

    location /administrator/ {
                auth_basic    "Admin-Section";
                auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;

                location ~ \.php {
                        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
                        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                        include fastcgi_params;
                }
        }

    location ~ \.php {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Когда вставляю в конфиг это, никакой реакции, переадресации страниц нет

```
location /текст/tekst2/ {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ http://dev2.site.com/tekst3/tekst4;
}
```

Может кто знает в чем может быть подвох?

Comment: в неправильном [кодировании не-ascii-символов в url](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Comment: К сожалению никакой реакции, генерирую такую вот ссылку



location /%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8B/text2 {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ http://dev2.site.com/text3/text4;
}